# Image not changing after dragging image from other web browser

Tags: jquery, dhtml

I tried to click and drag a photo or image and place on the kitten image, it didnt change but redirect me to the link of the image.  How can i fix that?  The code is supposed to let the image change instead of redirect me to the link.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Drag and Drop</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    function dragStart(jQueryEvent) {
        // Store URL
        var dataTransfer = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
        jQueryEvent.dataTransfer.setData('Text', dataTransfer);
        // photo being dragged and dropped  with <img> tag and set the photo. 
    }
    function dragOver() {
        return false;   // Indicates that the element can be dropped onto
    }
    function drop(jQueryEvent) {
        // Update image and text box
        jQueryEvent.preventDefault();
        var dataTransfer = jQueryEvent.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
        document.getElementsByTagName('img').innerHTML = jQueryEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text');     
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" style="width: 300px" value="http://placekitten.com/320/240" /><br />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/320/240" style="border: 1px solid grey; min-width: 50px; min-height: 50px; display: inline-block;" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `src` attribute, not `innerHTML`:

```
$("img")[0].src = jQueryEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text');
```

```js
dragDrop = {
 keyHTML: '<a href="#" class="keyLink">#</a>',
 keySpeed: 10, // pixels per keypress event
 initialMouseX: undefined,
 initialMouseY: undefined,
 startX: undefined,
 startY: undefined,
 dXKeys: undefined,
 dYKeys: undefined,
 draggedObject: undefined,
 initElement: function (element) {
  if (typeof element == 'string')
   element = document.getElementById(element);
  element.onmousedown = dragDrop.startDragMouse;
  element.innerHTML += dragDrop.keyHTML;
  var links = element.getElementsByTagName('a');
  var lastLink = links[links.length-1];
  lastLink.relatedElement = element;
  lastLink.onclick = dragDrop.startDragKeys;
 },
 startDragMouse: function (e) {
  dragDrop.startDrag(this);
  var evt = e || window.event;
  dragDrop.initialMouseX = evt.clientX;
  dragDrop.initialMouseY = evt.clientY;
  addEventSimple(document,'mousemove',dragDrop.dragMouse);
  addEventSimple(document,'mouseup',dragDrop.releaseElement);
  return false;
 },
 startDragKeys: function () {
  dragDrop.startDrag(this.relatedElement);
  dragDrop.dXKeys = dragDrop.dYKeys = 0;
  addEventSimple(document,'keydown',dragDrop.dragKeys);
  addEventSimple(document,'keypress',dragDrop.switchKeyEvents);
  this.blur();
  return false;
 },
 startDrag: function (obj) {
  if (dragDrop.draggedObject)
   dragDrop.releaseElement();
  dragDrop.startX = obj.offsetLeft;
  dragDrop.startY = obj.offsetTop;
  dragDrop.draggedObject = obj;
  obj.className += ' dragged';
 },
 dragMouse: function (e) {
  var evt = e || window.event;
  var dX = evt.clientX - dragDrop.initialMouseX;
  var dY = evt.clientY - dragDrop.initialMouseY;
  dragDrop.setPosition(dX,dY);
  return false;
 },
 dragKeys: function(e) {
  var evt = e || window.event;
  var key = evt.keyCode;
  switch (key) {
   case 37: // left
   case 63234:
    dragDrop.dXKeys -= dragDrop.keySpeed;
    break;
   case 38: // up
   case 63232:
    dragDrop.dYKeys -= dragDrop.keySpeed;
    break;
   case 39: // right
   case 63235:
    dragDrop.dXKeys += dragDrop.keySpeed;
    break;
   case 40: // down
   case 63233:
    dragDrop.dYKeys += dragDrop.keySpeed;
    break;
   case 13:  // enter
   case 27:  // escape
    dragDrop.releaseElement();
    return false;
   default:
    return true;
  }
  dragDrop.setPosition(dragDrop.dXKeys,dragDrop.dYKeys);
  if (evt.preventDefault)
   evt.preventDefault();
  return false;
 },
 setPosition: function (dx,dy) {
  dragDrop.draggedObject.style.left = dragDrop.startX + dx + 'px';
  dragDrop.draggedObject.style.top = dragDrop.startY + dy + 'px';
 },
 switchKeyEvents: function () {
  // for Opera and Safari 1.3
  removeEventSimple(document,'keydown',dragDrop.dragKeys);
  removeEventSimple(document,'keypress',dragDrop.switchKeyEvents);
  addEventSimple(document,'keypress',dragDrop.dragKeys);
 },
 releaseElement: function() {
  removeEventSimple(document,'mousemove',dragDrop.dragMouse);
  removeEventSimple(document,'mouseup',dragDrop.releaseElement);
  removeEventSimple(document,'keypress',dragDrop.dragKeys);
  removeEventSimple(document,'keypress',dragDrop.switchKeyEvents);
  removeEventSimple(document,'keydown',dragDrop.dragKeys);
  dragDrop.draggedObject.className = dragDrop.draggedObject.className.replace(/dragged/,'');
  dragDrop.draggedObject = null;
 }
}
```

**References**

- [Drag and drop](http://www.quirksmode.org/m/tests/drag.html)
- [DOM tests - elementFromPoint](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/tests/elementfrompoint.html)